# How to Implement DataSheet

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uicollectionview

I want to implement data sheet to display history of user. I want to implement that design like this:

[image]

But I dont know how to do that...Can anyone please help me

Edit:
[image]

Comment: The way is to achieve this using custome Table Cell

Comment: by adding label to cell???

Comment: Yes, create a custom cell, Add label and background to give the feel like table

Comment: but there will be space between two row...

Comment: ok let me try this and then I will comment...

Comment: Yes space can be maintain using spring or autolayout and background for cellView can give the feel of table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the horizontal line at the specific position and the label at the position and it will look like this.

Create a tableview and than in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method add this code..

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier;
    UITableViewCell * cell;

    SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";
    cell = [tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: nil];

    if(cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];


        UILabel * numLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,5,33,30)];
        numLbl.text = @"1";
        [numLbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:10.0]];
        numLbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [cell addSubview:numLbl];

        UILabel * nameLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30,5,50,30)];
        nameLbl.text = @"john%Lakeview";
        [nameLbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:10.0]];
        nameLbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [cell addSubview:nameLbl];


        //create a hoizontal separator in cell to display it like column
        UIView* hSeparatorview1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 0, 1, 30)];
        hSeparatorview1.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        hSeparatorview1.tag = 1;
        [cell addSubview:hSeparatorview1];

        UIView* hSeparatorview2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(85, 0, 1, 30)];
        hSeparatorview2.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        hSeparatorview2.tag = 2;
        [cell addSubview:hSeparatorview2];
    }

    return cell;
}

//this method is used to set the hight of the tableview cell
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath      *)indexPath;
{
    return 30;
}
```

I have created it for only two label and two horizontal view but you can create as many as you like.

And yes dot forget to place this code in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` otherwise horizontal view will disappear when user click the cell.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)atableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //get the cell which is selected
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [atableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    //set cell horizontal saparator view color of selected cell bcoz when cell selected all view color is gone
    UIView *hSeparatorview1=[selectedCell viewWithTag:1];
    hSeparatorview1.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    UIView *hSeparatorview2=[selectedCell viewWithTag:2];
    hSeparatorview2.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

}
```

Comment: Its bcoz your text is large and the size of label is small.

Comment: Either increase the size of label or decrease the font size of label

Comment: @vivek i have given answer for this problem. If you want more help than ask another question. If this answer has helped you in this problem than accept it.

Comment: Yes but still I didnt get exact view thats why...And I will accept your answer only because I have used your code...

Comment: I think you have got it.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20786570/remove-header-and-footer

Comment: You just not giving the exact position. And we cant set the position for you thats you have to do on your own.

Comment: The answer is always to set you on right path not for doing your work by other.

Comment: And i think my answer has set you on right path. now on you have to customize it for your need.

Comment: Got it but if I have some doubt then may I ask you or not?

Comment: Definitely but it must be belong to this question not other.

Comment: becuse I think if I accept your answer then may be you will not reply my another query related to it

Comment: Vivek we are here for help not for point. Point wont earn me money. Sometime you wont get reply at the instant, But that bcoz we all have work to do. But whenever i got time i will help you in your query as best i can.

Comment: Point is just for that future user know that this answer has helped the previous user. so he can find the best answer for him from the other.

Answer (score 0):

Better to try with Custom tableview Cell for text,and UIViews for lines.I'm also done the same in my app.

Comment: How to use UIView for lines?

Comment: exist the frames as per your requirement through XIB.