# Remove Header and Footer

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I want to remove header and footer from my 'UITableView'
I have tried:

```
table.tableHeaderView = nil;

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
            viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
   return nil;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
           heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{     
    return 0;
}
```

But none of this working.
[image]

I want to start my section from starting of tableview.

Comment: delete both methods...

Comment: @vivek What happened when you try it.

Comment: Try this - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return [UIView new];
}

Comment: @Zaph..its just showing same result

Comment: Are you sure these areas are part of the tableview? Try [Spark Inspector](http://sparkinspector.com), free for 30 days, no code changes are needed for use in the simulator.

Comment: remove data source connection you your table view to make sure that these methods have some effect on your code or not

Comment: @ShreeshGarg....when I wrote this method it has no effect in header.
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    UIView *v=[[UIView alloc]init];
    v.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    return v;
}

Comment: header is nil....I got it..portion seen in above screen shot is part of tableview but not header...

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Please mark the correct answer to mark this post as answered.

Comment: @亚历山大 yes. just set one view to tableView.tableHeaderView and tableView.tableFooterView property.

Comment: Did one of the answers help you with your problem? Then mark it or write your solution if it differs from the answers. Otherwise this post won't be marked as answered.

Comment: no...just look at my comment...in answers thye are setting view for header...while I was needed for table...that's why tableview.tableHeaderView is used.both are different

Answer (score 1):

When I try to do this, what usually ends up working is:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
            viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below. It may help you.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
          heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0.1; 
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
          heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section { 
    return 0.1; 
}
```

You can also do this by setting the `contentInset` property of your `UITableView`.

Answer (score 0):

@Vivek, Just remove all unnecessarily implemented method will also work.I have same scenario but not facing any issue with `header` and `footer`.

I think this only following methods needed.

```
   - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
                numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{}

   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
                        cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{}
```

Comment: with those two methods...scenario will be according above screenshot...I am using tableview style group

Comment: @Vivek if not needed then use simple table instead of grouped table.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
           heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 0.1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
            viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
} 

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
            viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView     
          heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0.1f;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView      
          heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0.1f;
}
```

Hope this will be helpful for you.