# Tableview scrolling enable

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Initially I have two row in table view at that time i don't want to enable scrolling...
But if number of row increase then visible part I want to allow scrolling...
I tried with this code but it is not working...and I don't know where to check this condition and how to find content size of table view.
Can anyone please provide me solution for this or better solution than this:

```
tableView.contentSize.height <= tableView.frame.height
 NSLog(@"%f",historyTable.contentSize.width);
```

I have Log width in viewwill appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The movement you can see while content is limited to view area is not scrolling it is bouncing.

Bouncing is feature of UIScrollView which is parent class of UITableView.

You can turn it ON or OFF by using following BOOl property.

> @property(nonatomic) BOOL bounces

It you case set it to NO : `[tableView setBounces:YES]`

The disadvantage of setting this property to NO is scroll don't feel good. But it depend on your need.

If you are using Storyboard to make table view you can set it in interface also.

Comment: another thing I want to know from you that what should I use to achieve view like this? Look at this question   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20779979/how-to-implement-datasheet/20780059?noredirect=1#comment31174212_20780059

Comment: Collectionview or tableview?

Comment: If you are talking about image in that question than UITableView only.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try something like this :

```
tableView.scrollEnabled = NUMBER_OF_ROWS * CELL_HEIGHT > tableView.bounds.size.height;
```

It should work

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what was said in the previous answers, you should consider to move the checkings to the viewDidAppear method, since at the moment of executing viewWillAppear, the properties of the frame are not set yet.